# textDidChange(_:) method not triggering during typing in KeyboardKit-based keyboard extension

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm encountering an issue with the `textDidChange(_:)` method in my KeyboardKit-based keyboard extension. Currently, the `textDidChange(_:)` method gets triggered only when there's no text in the input field, and pressing backspace twice, instead of triggering during regular typing.

The `textDidChange(_:)` method should ideally get called whenever the text content changes, including during regular typing or when characters are added or removed from the text input field.
However, it appears to only trigger when the input field is empty, and the backspace key is pressed.

Ensured proper handling of text insertion and deletion methods within the KeyboardKit-based extension.

Reviewed keyboard state and actions to ensure they interact correctly with the text input field.

Inspected KeyboardKit configuration for any potential issues affecting text change events.

Comment: Is it this KeyboardKit? https://github.com/KeyboardKit/KeyboardKit

Comment: yes, It is using this package.

Answer (score 0):

The `textDidChange` and `textWillChange` in the UIInputViewController methods are for notifying the keyboard of changes made to the 'documents contents' by the app that the, not those caused by the keyboard itself.

Comment: then is there any way of getting those changes that are made by the keyboard itself, as I want that text to do further processing?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, but is your extension itself not the thing that at some point inserts characters?

Comment: yes my extension is the thing that enters the characters.